# Better data method with Material-UI Tables

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

All the of the examples in Material-UI v1 have table examples have the below as an example of the format for data in tables:

```
data: [
  createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData('Donut', 452, 25.0, 51, 4.9),
  createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData('Honeycomb', 408, 3.2, 87, 6.5),
  createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData('Jelly Bean', 375, 0.0, 94, 0.0),
  createData('KitKat', 518, 26.0, 65, 7.0),
  createData('Lollipop', 392, 0.2, 98, 0.0),
  createData('Marshmallow', 318, 0, 81, 2.0),
  createData('Nougat', 360, 19.0, 9, 37.0),
  createData('Oreo', 437, 18.0, 63, 4.0),
]
```

However before v1 I could do an array like below which I find to be more efficient. My question is, how do you do it in v1 because it just seems tedious to write each row as createData etc..

```
const tableData = [
  {
    name: 'John Smith',
    status: 'Employed',
    selected: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Randal White',
    status: 'Unemployed',
  },
  {
    name: 'Stephanie Sanders',
    status: 'Employed',
    selected: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Steve Brown',
    status: 'Employed',
  },
  {
    name: 'Joyce Whitten',
    status: 'Employed',
  },
  {
    name: 'Samuel Roberts',
    status: 'Employed',
  },
  {
    name: 'Adam Moore',
    status: 'Employed',
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see:

```
let id = 0;
function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  id += 1;
  return { id, name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}
```

what `createData` does is adding an id for the table values

This is more like the opinion you are asking

that id is used in here:

```
<TableRow key={n.id}>
 <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
   {n.name}
 </TableCell>
 <TableCell numeric>{n.calories}</TableCell>
 <TableCell numeric>{n.fat}</TableCell>
 <TableCell numeric>{n.carbs}</TableCell>
 <TableCell numeric>{n.protein}</TableCell>
</TableRow>
```

if you are using data from a database then you can use ID from the db generated.

both ways are fine as long as what is easier for you to do.

if you are using this just for testing purposes you can use

```
{todos.map((todo, index) =>
  <Todo
    {...todo}
    key={index}
  />
)}
```

but this is not a good practice. read more from here: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318